# Menu Rendering before styles are applied. Webkit Browsers only, possible reasons why?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I am working on a project for a client. The site is large, with a lot of scripts and for non-disclosure reasons I can't add a link.

The probably seems to be only in Webkit browsers. Before the page is loaded the menu appears completely unstyled before jumping to the styled version.

The menu is rendered as a block, but I have also tried adding it via the template to no avail.

I have moved the navigation css to render immediately after the system.css files.

No other blocks/views are behaving like this. When the site goes live it will have it's own opcache and cloudflare for extra speed and caching but we'd like to eliminate the problem prior to that.

Can anyone suggest what may be the issue? Or has anyone come across anything similar? Any advice would be appreciated.